# parse PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have managed to get to the stage where I have an array that looks like this. Used (zend_json to decode a json response)

```
Array
(
[response] => Array
    (
        [status] => ok
        [userTier] => free
        [total] => 10
        [startIndex] => 1
        [pageSize] => 10
        [currentPage] => 1
        [pages] => 1
        [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => lifeandstyle/series/cycling
                        [type] => series
                        [webTitle] => Cycling
                        [webUrl] => http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/series/cycling
                        [apiUrl] => http://content.guardianapis.com/lifeandstyle/series/cycling
                        [sectionId] => lifeandstyle
                        [sectionName] => Life and style
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => sport/cycling
                        [type] => keyword
                        [webTitle] => Cycling
                        [webUrl] => http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/cycling
                        [apiUrl] => http://content.guardianapis.com/sport/cycling
                        [sectionId] => sport
                        [sectionName] => Sport
                    )
```

How would I go about parsing only the elements that are [webTitle] and [webUrl]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specifically parse only those parts, but you can iterate over the results and access them.

```
foreach ($val['response']['results'] as $result) {
  $title = $result['webTitle']; 
  $url = $result['webUrl'];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) would my syntax be - 

require_once 'Zend/Json.php';   //load Json library
$val = Zend_Json::decode($response_api);  //decode he result into something thats parseable
foreach ($array['response']['results'] as $val) {
  $title = $result['webTitle']; 
  $url = $result['webUrl'];

  // ...
}

Comment: You didn't give the name of your variable in your post, so I used `$array`, but it should be `$val`

Comment: perfect, one more question wouldnt i make it so the webUrl was a clickable link when echoed out

Comment: Any logic you have for displaying this is up to you. Just output the values into HTML however you would do it normally.